# Bootstrap modal's data-dismiss on close modal not closing audio in mozila and IE

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am using bootstrap modal pop up for showing audio/videos attached in the project.
On clicking the cancel button the modal should close and the audio should stop playing.
This is working correctly in Chrome but in both mozila and IE whan I click cancel the modal dismisses but aduio/video continues playing.

This is the HAML code for modal pop-up:

```
%a{ href: "#", class: "x", title: "Close", :'data-dismiss' => "modal" }
    .diagRepeater &nbsp;

    = swf_tag "StrobeMediaPlayback",
      :width => '620',
      :height => (attachment.media_content_type.split('/')[0] == 'audio' ? '65' : '340'),
      :flashvars => { :urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance => "true",
      :src => URI.encode("#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}" + attachment.media.url),
      :playButtonOverlay => (attachment.media_content_type.split('/')[0] == 'audio' ? 'false' : 'true'),
      :controlBarAutoHide => (attachment.media_content_type.split('/')[0] == 'audio' ? 'false' : 'true') },
      :parameters => { :allowFullScreen => "true", :wmode => "direct",     :allowScriptAccess => "always" }
```

And this is the code in bootstrap.js file:

```
hide: function (e) {
e && e.preventDefault()

    var that = this
    alert(this.toString());
    e = $.Event('hide')

    this.$element.trigger(e)

    if (!this.isShown || e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.isShown = false

    $('body').removeClass('modal-open')

    escape.call(this)

    this.$element.removeClass('in')

    $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('fade') ?
      hideWithTransition.call(this) :
      hideModal.call(this)
  }
```

Comment: When you dismiss the modal, you can call an action to your video to stop the play.

Comment: How to do this can u please explain a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way if you are having any troubles just use below code and clear html of modal first and put it again and it should work everytime:

```
$('.x').live('click',function(){
    var media_html = '';
    $('.modalBox').each(function(){
         media_html = $(this).html();
         $(this).html('');
         $(this).html(media_html);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('.x').click(function(){
    var myAudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
    if(myAudio != undefined){
        myAudio.StopPlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Scott, Thanks for quick answer but it did not work for me. It is giving error that stopPlay() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

This really should not be too hard. I am thinking that there is an issue with your javascript. Have you implemented Bootstrap like this Railscasts explains? I've never had any issues with modals and videos.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="mydemo">Open Video</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> <iframe width="470" height="310" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.mydemo').click(function () {
            var src = 

'http://www.youtube.com/v/2EnI9K8Fkf4&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#myModal iframe').attr('src', src);
            });

        $('#myModal.modal').bind('hide', function () {
            var iframe = $(this).children('div.modal-body').find('iframe');
            var src = iframe.attr('src');
            iframe.attr('src', '');
            iframe.attr('src', src);
            });

</script>
```

This code works perfect on IE.